# Rake test suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working with my rails application and since today I have not been able to run `rake test:units`

I though maybe my Ruby installation is broken or something, so I tried creating a new application, created a new model quickly, wrote a couple of unit test and then ran them. Everything seems to be running fine with the new app.

Please check the error log generated here http://pastebin.com/jgNXpXE3

Comment: Can you include the code from the top of product.rb?

Comment: @nickgrim - yes my product model had some invalid lines, causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there's a bug in your `Product` model. Do you have a call to `validates` without any parameters passed to it?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Comment: wow !! that was awesome. Really man. Yesterday I was testing my Git installation and I added some rubbish validation just to create a new commit.